# #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: denwer

Почему такое выскакивает? Как его обойти?

Comment: Потому что для пользователя root стоит пароль, например.

Comment: но я его ведь не ставил. Как отключить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Это происходит из-за попытки подключения к базе без пароля, хотя он необходим,
если вы не устанавливали пароль попробуйте ввести root, root (логин, пароль)
иногда, так стоит по умолчанию, более точно можно посмотреть и при неоходимости отключить просто удалив строчку напротив password в конфиге
здесь Z:\home\localhost\www\Tools\phpmyadmin\config.inc.php

```
Попробуйте проделать такие шаги:
 1. Нажмите stop Denwer
 2. Заходи в папку где установлен у вас денвер например(c:\WebServers\usr\local\mysql-5.1\) там в файлик my.cnf, в нем после [mysqld] пишем skip-grant-tables.
 3. Теперь запускаем денвер, заходим http://localhost/Tools/phpMyAdmin/ в вкладку SQL и вставляем такой код MyNewPass это ваш новый пароль
    UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
 4. Выключаем денвер, стираем в my.cnf skip-grant-tables, запускаем денвер
 5. Редактируем такие строчки в config.inc.php

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root'; 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MyNewPass';
```

Comment: А точнее? Какую строку удалить?

Comment: ну помогите разобраться!